# Is there any way to send the packet per minute with tcpreplay ?

Tags: tcpreplay

I am using tcpreplay to send traffic . I know the -p option for packet per second, but I want to send packet per minute.

Comment: have you read this ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164390/how-do-i-pump-traffic-using-tcpreplay-at-100-mbps-500-mbps-and-1gbps-speeds

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can think of a viable solution since the --pps option doesn't support fractions.  The only way you might be able to do that is use the --mbps option and select a slow enough traffic rate that tcpreplay only sends one packet per minute, but that will only be accurate if your packets are the same size.

Your probably best bet is to open a feature request: https://github.com/appneta/tcpreplay/issues